# If Statement Not Working In JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor

What I am trying to achieve is to get the name of the anchor link, which I have done, but for some weird reason it will not work within an if statement. 
I have alerted the anchors name successfully but no matter what it won't within a if statement. Any ideas why?

Thanks

```
    echo "<br> 
    <div id='clicked_linked_$post_id_row' class='comment_field'>

    <div id='showit_$post_id_row' style='display:none;'>
<form action='' method='POST''>
<textarea name='comment_post' class='comment_post'placeholder='What Is Your Thought?'></textarea>
<input type='hidden' name='post_id_value' id='post_id_value' class='post_id_value' value='$post_id_row'><br>
<input type='submit' value='Reply'>
</form>
</div>
<small> <a href='#' class='comment_link' id='$post_id_row'> Comment$post_id_row </a> </small>

</div><br>
";
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('.comment_link').click(function() {
var t = $(this).text();
alert(t);
if($(this).text()=='Comment64') {
alert(9);
}

});

$(document).on("click", ".comment_link", function(){



 var id = this.id; 

     $('#showit_'+id).fadeIn(1000);

     return false;

});
});
```

Comment: This question is impossible to understand. Please make the effort to write correct english phrases.

Comment: I am bascially saying if statements are not working at all in jquery

Comment: can you post your markup of anchor.

Comment: You're binding the `click` event twice - does any of them work the way you want? [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/7zc87/) - works properly.

Comment: Yeah since it didnt work in the secound click method I tried another method still didn't work remember this is just test code not production and I posted the archor and form code

Comment: Post a fiddle, please.

Comment: can't jfiddle won't allow PHP to be executed otherwise I would I do apologize though

Comment: See my answer. And next time, you can put the output of your php ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your anchors you have spaces arouund text, ie. `_Comment64_` instead of `Comment64`, where `_` is a space. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/7zc87/1/).

Comment: Yep thanks loads :D thought it be something with the jquery not the actual HTML I would vote up but don't have another rep but I accepted it
thanks heaps mate!

Answer (score 1):

correct it

```
if(this.text=='Comment64')
```

with

```
if(t=='Comment64')
```

or

```
if($(this).text()=='Comment64')
```

Comment: still doesen't work :/ I find it strange how it won't work in any if statements but alerts it fine and thanks for trying to help ;)

Comment: try to `alert(t);` before using if

Comment: change your `alert(9);` to `alert("9");`

Comment: still nothing just weird that its not doing what im telling it to do

Comment: r u trying to hit correct file. make another demo file and try only this particular jquery in that file.